# Unmet Peer Dependency TSLint/Codelyzer

Tags: angular, npm, tslint

After upgrading to TSLint 5.0.0 I now get the following error:

```
myapp-web@2.0.0 /Projects/myapp-web
├── codelyzer@2.1.1
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY tslint@5.0.0
```